# Pairs scatter plot; one vs many

Tags: r

Is there a parsimonious way to create a `pairs` plot that only compares one variable to the many others? In other words, can I plot just one row or column of the standard `pairs` scatter plot matrix without using a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Melt your data then use ggplot with facet.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

#dummy data
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,
                 a=runif(10),
                 b=runif(10),
                 c=runif(10))

#melt your data
df_melt <- melt(df,"x")

#scatterplot per group
ggplot(df_melt,aes(x,value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(.~variable)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'll round it out with a base plotting option (using `df` from @zx8754):

```
layout(matrix(seq(ncol(df)-1),nrow=1))
Map(function(x,y) plot(df[c(x,y)]), names(df[1]), names(df[-1]))
```

[image: yeah]

Although arguably this is still a loop using `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

For the fun, with `lattice` (with @zx8754 "df_melt"):

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(value ~ x | variable, data = df_melt, layout = c(3,1), 
       between = list(x=1))
```

[image]